# some information on timer_helper_thread() of librt.so.1

Tags: linux, posix

Can anybody give some information on timer_helper_thread() function of librt.so.1.
I am using posix timer_create() function in my application for timer functionality and i am using SIEV_THREAD for notifiction. When timeout happens, i could see in gdb that two thread are getting created. One is the thread whose start function i have specified and another is the thread whose start function is timer_help_therad() of librt.so.1. Among these two timer_helper_thread() is not exiting even after my thread is exiting. Can anbody tell me when will timer_helper_thread() exit and give some informatin on it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't worry about it; it's an implementation detail and will clean up after itself when your program exits.  But if you're curious...

From glibc's `timer_create(2)` man page:

> SIGEV_THREAD:
>   Upon  timer  expiration,  invoke  sigev_notify_function as if it were the start function of a new thread.  (Among the implementation  possibilities  here are that each timer notification could result in the creation of a new thread, or that a single  thread is  created  to  receive  all  notifications.)

And also:

> The functionality  for  SIGEV_THREAD  is  implemented within glibc, rather than the kernel.

So glibc (i.e. librt.so) assumes that the kernel cannot create a thread in response to a timer event -- that all it supports is sending a signal.  So someone needs to receive that signal and create the handler thread.  If you wanted to muck with the details of receiving the signal yourself, you wouldn't have used SIGEV_THREAD, so glibc doesn't bother you and instead creates its own thread just for handling timer events.

This timer helper thread lasts from the fist time you call `timer_create()` until your program ends.  Unless you're doing something unusual, you don't need to worry about it; it will clean up after itself when your program exits.  The only thing it does is wait for a timer to expire, so it's not using up any extra processing power.  Furthermore, it looks like there will only ever be the one helper thread, no matter how many timers you create.

Comment: @jander....thanks jander...I have one more query to ask u..Since the first time timeout happens, my process's memory usage will be increased by the  size of the thread stack (which i can find out by "ulimit -s" on my linux machine) as this thread is created at run time...Am i right?

Comment: @abcd: Looks right to me.  You can also specify the size of your thread stack using the `sigev_notify_attributes` field in your `struct sigevent`.  On my machine, the helper thread looks like it's using a 128kB stack, but my timer handlers used the maximum `ulimit -s` size.

Comment: how did u find out the memory usage of helper thread? can u tell me how to find out? For me it seems that it is consuming around 10 mb which is "ulimit_s". How I arrived at this conclusion is the vrt column of top command's output for my procces is increasing by 10 mb after first timeout. Tell me how to find out the memory usage for helper thread.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after `timer_create()` but before `timer_settime()`, and check the memory usage at that point (vs. usage before `timer_create()`.  I've been using /proc/*pid*/status to check the memory usage, but top should work too.

Answer (score 0):

@jander: Your comment is interesting here "This timer helper thread lasts from the fist time you call timer_create() until your program ends." 
There are threads created on everytime a timer is timeout. Is this same as the timer_helper_thread() you mention? 
I have a similar post where I observe a separate thread created only for timer_create(). Would this be the timer_helper_thread()? 
Ref: [New thread on invocation of timer_create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927114/new-thread-on-invocation-of-timer-create)