# New thread on invocation of timer_create()

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

I am investigating how to get thread ID when the function timer_create() is called.
I observed that everytime the timer_create() is called, a new thread (child thread of main process) is created. I verified this with ps -eL|grep

I need to get the same TID (child thread ID) displayed by ps -eL inside my program which uses timer_create.
From code below: How do I get the TID 18018 inside my program?

I have researched all the posts and each one mentions that a new thread is created on calling the notification function and not calling timer_create().

I appreciate your help very much!

Code:

```
SLGTRACER_DEFINE(testMain, "testMain");


timer_t audit_timer1;

void timeoutHandler(sigval_t info)
{
    slgInfo(testMain, "timeoutHandler invoked");

    slgInfo(testMain, "gettid() = %lu TESTMAIN", syscall(SYS_gettid));
    slgInfo(testMain, "getpid() = %d TESTMAIN", getpid());

}

int main(void)
{
    slgInfo(testMain, "testMain Invoked");


    struct sigevent evp1;
    evp1.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    evp1.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &audit_timer1;
    evp1.sigev_notify_function = timeoutHandler;
    evp1.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

    const int ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE = 50;


       slgInfo(testMain, "Before FIRST timer_create");
       sleep(30);


    // Create timer thread
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &evp1, &audit_timer1) != 0)
    {
       // Character buffer for storing error message.
        char     errBuff[ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE];

        memset(errBuff, 0, ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE);

        slgError(testMain,
                    "timer_start create failed. Error = %s",
                    strerror_r(errno, errBuff, ERROR_BUFFER_SIZE));

        timer_delete(audit_timer1);
        bzero(&audit_timer1, sizeof(audit_timer1));
    }


       slgInfo(testMain, "After FIRST timer_create");
       sleep(30); 

    return 0;

}
```

```
bash-3.1# ps -eL|grep testM
16651 16651 pts/0    00:00:00 testMain
16651 18018 pts/0    00:00:00 testMain 
child thread with ID created by timer_create() = 18018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a thread even exists before the timeout handler gets called is unspecified. Certainly a conformant implementation could defer creation of the thread until the timer expires. The existence of numeric thread ids that look like pids is also an implementation detail, one which you should not use.

Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Surely there is a better way...

Comment: After multiple testing, I found out that there is a child thread created when timer_create() is called. I am trying to get that thread ID in my program. I will use that thread ID to set scheduling option for that thread.

Comment: Yes, a thread exists after timer_create() is called and before timeoutHandler() is called.

Comment: @LinuxNewbie If that's what you need, you can specify a pthread_attr_t as the sigev_notify_attributes member of struct sigevent. That way you can initialize the thread with attributes set by e.g pthread_attr_setschedpolicy . You should update/change your question with this new information.

Comment: See nos's comment for the correct way to do what you want. And note that my answer and references to "implementation details" are assuming that you want to write a portable program that works on other operating systems and future Linux versions, not just the present version with the present implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Actually, I have tried that, but it does not take effect in scheduling option. It inherits sched options from main process. What I am looking for, is getting the ID for thread created for timer_create().

Comment: Are you sure you're doing it right? Show us the code that's not working. In any case, the priority of the thread will be irrelevant until the timer expiration function is actually called (since it's sleeping), so you could just set the priority in the timer expiration function itself as soon as it's called...

Comment: pthread_attr_t timer_thread_attr;
    struct sched_param timer_thread_param;
    struct sigevent evp;
    evp.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    evp.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &audit_timer;
    evp.sigev_notify_function = timeoutHandler;
    pthread_attr_init(&timer_thread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&timer_thread_attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&timer_thread_attr, SCHED_RR);
    timer_thread_param.sched_priority = 84;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&timer_thread_attr, &timer_thread_param);
    evp.sigev_notify_attributes = &timer_thread_attr;

Comment: @LinuxNewbie are you running as root (or have the CAP_SYS_NICE capability on your executable), as you're not allowed to set SCHED_RR as an arbitary user

Comment: yes - my main process is running as root - however these thread attributes which I set, will reflect on threads created for handling timeout handler, and not the thread which is created on calling timer_create(). Since timer_create() does not return thread ID or have a start function, I don't think I can get TID inside my program.

Comment: Also found about timer helper thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263958/some-information-on-timer-helper-thread-of-librt-so-1/4935895#4935895 - if this is created on calling timer_create(), there should be a way to get the TID.

Comment: You keep asking about "TID" (Linux-specific pid-like number) when this is not something that exists in the POSIX threads model (at least you're not supposed to see it from your application). Are you by chance using some ancient system with "LinuxThreads" (completely non-POSIX-conformant) instead of NPTL?

Comment: sorry for any confusion - Initially I thought I would be able to rename thread using TID. However, I can work with pthread ID if I can get the pthread ID for thread created on calling timer_create(). I am using Linux kernel 2.6.18 for compile, NPTL 2.5.

Comment: Why is it insufficient to just set the priority from the timeout handler as soon as it runs?

Comment: The reason is that setting the priority from timeout handler will take effect on threads created by timeout handler, and not take effect on thread created on timer_create(). My test objective is to set name and set priority of the thread created by timer_create().

Comment: OK, I see, now you're really into the realm of poking at implementation details. I think you have two options. You can either set the scheduling priority of the calling thread before calling `timer_create` the first time, and hope the new thread inherits that. Or you can poke around at libc internals, and have fun explaining it to your boss when your program suddenly breaks at some future date because the implementation internals changed. :-)

Comment: Thanks! will try first option...seems better :)